# Passenger + Nginx on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to setup new server, but nginx is unable to load directive "passenger_enabled".

```
May 03 11:35:28 xxxx nginx[11181]: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "passenger_enabled" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:25
May 03 11:35:28 xxxx nginx[11181]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I think I installed it right:

```
dorijan@xxxxxx:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras passenger
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nginx-extras is already the newest version (1.14.0-0ubuntu1).
passenger is already the newest version (5.0.30-1build2).
```

in nginx.conf I have

...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;
...

and /etc/nginx/passenger.conf contains:

```
dorijan@xxxxxx:/etc/nginx$ cat passenger.conf
passenger_ruby /home/dorijan/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.5.0/ruby;
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
```

and default site configuration is:

```
    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
            server_name xxxx.local;
            passenger_enabled on;
            rails_env    development;
            root /home/dorijan/ruby/xxxxx/public;
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no nginx package with a passenger module in the bionic repositores yet, right? You might want to check if the module is included in your nginx by

```
nginx -V
```

I also did not find a suitable libnginx-mod-http-passenger anywhere.

Comment: ok, I post a issue https://github.com/phusion/passenger_apt_automation/issues/22

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install -y nginx
```

Installing nginx is still needed after following the instructions https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/nginx/oss/bionic/install_passenger.html